# Foreign key hierarchy including parent-child-child relationship

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I've a of lot of tables with foreign key constraints. 
My idea is, I do a archival on many tables since it has too much of inter related foreign key constrains it is difficult to find a child table to start deletion.

Is there any script or Stored procedure where I can input a table name and it will list out all the child tables. Listing out child tables in the sense that it should satisfy the below scenario

**Table A** is Parent

**Table Ab** is a child of A

**Table Ac** is also a child of A

Inorder to delete A, I need to delete Ab and Ac first. But here it is

**Table Abc** is a child of **Ab**

So I need to delete **Abc** first then **Ab**, **Ac**(assuming no child of Ac) to delete **A**.

This is the query that I'm using,

```
select TABLE_NAME,REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE 
where   REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME ='A'
```

Right now, I'm finding the details manually one by one is there any other way that I can achieve it ?

Comment: I would suggest : prepare a nice ER Diagram

Comment: Its on the cards, but like I said more than 500 tables like it is tedious to find out.

Comment: This sounds like an off-topic resource request to me